# Who to customize media URL in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, thumbor

[image: Media file url]

Is there any way to customize file URL ?

Comment: you will need to upload the file with desired name you want in the url

Answer (score 1):

Could you let us know how you want it customized?

In Settings>Media you can uncheck "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders".

You could use a plugin like [WP Original Media Path](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-original-media-path/)

You could add/modify this line in your wp-config.php as detailed [here](https://zonewp.com/2019/05/customize-the-wordpress-wp-config-file/)

```
// Moving the uploads directory
define( 'UPLOADS', 'uploads' );
```

Comment: there is something called thumbor is a smart imaging service it use like this
http://0.0.0.0:8888/unsafe/300x200/[image_url]
i want to make file URL which is read only  to be changeable so that I can select a size to every image in wordpress